# match response while ignoring array order

Tags: karate

Given following response:

```
* def resp = {"a":[{"c": 2},{"c": 1}, {"c":3}], "b":[6,5,4]}
```

I want to match it no matter the order arrays are in.

I know I could do it with `contains` directive but I think that would require me to do multiple match patterns like:

```
  * match resp.a.[*].c contains [3,2,1]
  * match resp.b contains [5,4,6]
```

Is there something like global config to ignore array order all together or do I have to roll with contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works. You could also specify the size of the array if you want for example.

```
    * def response = {"a":[2,1,3], "b":[6,5,4]}
    * match response.a contains [3,2,1]
    * match response.b contains [5,4,6]
    * match response == {"a": "#[] #? _ <4, _ >0", "b": "#[] #? _ <7, _ >3"}
```

Edit to match your more detailed case :

```
    * def resp = {"a":[{"c": 2},{"c": 1}, {"c":3}], "b":[6,5,4]}
    * def inside = {"c" : "#number"}
    * def schema = { "a": "#[] #(inside)", "b": "#[] #number" }
    * match resp == schema
```

Comment: `contains` I specified above and I want to avoid it for responses where there are multiple arrays which don't come in order, size of the array does not work for me, but its a neat trick to know anyhow. @Adrien ty ty

Comment: The two `contains` lines are not needed. I just reused them because they were in your code. But the last line checks that `a` is an array of numbers between 1 and 3, and that `b` is an array of numbers between 4 and 6. Is it what you want?

Comment: Y y i got it for contain ofc :) mmm i see, can it do values tho? Or like objects, i just figured my example is too simple, i would need to match array of objects as well.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to use some schema matching. Can you edit your question with the structure of your objects so I can provide an example? Let me know when it's done by commenting below.

Comment: I see, even tho I'm not satisfied with the solution, expected magic wand to make all arrays orders not matter, I assume this would be the best answer one could get, thank you for your time <3 @Adrien