# Not able to match same json which has mismatch in indexes of array of objects (Karate)

Tags: karate

Trying to match two jsons, but getting test fails. Well, both jsons are the same but objects indexes inside the array are not same. I think should not make any difference. Following are two jsons:
This is the code line: And match response contains ScenarioModelResponse where
**response : **

```
{
"relationships": [
{
"sourceId": "36",
"targetId": "149",
"type": "Reid Enright"
}
],
"modelId": "027f93d1-ef9e-4f1e-b2c4-684436c5b18a",
"elements": [
{
"externalRefId": "36",
"attributes": {
"jsonPbject": "Reid Enright"
},
"id": "057f7b7e-11b9-4779-97c0-67485153c285",
"type": "Rocky Shore"
},
{
"externalRefId": "149",
"attributes": {
"jsonPbject": "Ben Lyon"
},
"id": "325b989e-b299-4cfc-86b5-0813106da38e",
"type": "Claire Voyance"
}
]
}
```

ScenarioModelResponse :

```
{
"relationships": [
{
"sourceId": "36",
"targetId": "149",
"type": "Reid Enright"
}
],
"modelId": "027f93d1-ef9e-4f1e-b2c4-684436c5b18a",
"elements": [
{
"externalRefId": "149",
"attributes": {
"jsonPbject": "Ben Lyon"
},
"id": "325b989e-b299-4cfc-86b5-0813106da38e",
"type": "Claire Voyance"
},
{
"externalRefId": "36",
"attributes": {
"jsonPbject": "Reid Enright"
},
"id": "057f7b7e-11b9-4779-97c0-67485153c285",
"type": "Rocky Shore"
}
]
}
```

This the error I am getting after execution :

```
    $.elements[0].externalRefId | not equal (STRING:STRING)
    '149'
    '36'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays are NOT the same. This can be solved in 2 lines:

```
* match response.relationships == expected.relationships
* match response.elements contains only expected.elements
```

For a detailed explanation, refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65939070/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55710769/143475

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Thomas :)